# Passing variable as index to bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, awk

I tried to find the answer on this and other forums. The following is a bash script that is supposed to run a sequence of commands within a for loop. I am reading in 2 columns from a file. The first column has a list of file names (FARR) and the second a parameter - a number (NARR) used in the processing. It will run the set of commands for every file in FARR and use file name and parameter in the command starting after "do". Everything works as it should except the ${NARR[$N]} does not add the parameter to the end of the line. The parameter is blank at this stage.
Using echo $NARR brings up the full list. So the data is there...
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR='gauss_data/'
declare -i N=0
FARR=$(cat $DIR'all.dat' | awk '{if (NR!=1) print $1}')
NARR=$(cat $DIR'all.dat' | awk '{if (NR!=1) print $2}')
for f in $FARR;
do
    ./gauss_and_noise.py -i $DIR$f -o $DIR$f'.out' -d --save $DIR$f'.out.plot.png' --n0 ${NARR[$N]}
    let "N++"
done
```

Comment: You seem to be familiar with Python. I would rewrite this bash script in Python if I was you.

Comment: **Tip:** Adding `set -x` below the shebang line is a great assistance when debugging [tag:bash] scripts.

Comment: I could have done this in python, but I am teaching myself bash scripting and this seemed like a good candidate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say `NARR` is an array, but you are giving it a string value

Perhaps change to this

```
NARR=($(awk 'NR>1 {print $2}' "$DIR"all.dat))
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition, to iterate over an array, use this syntax:

```
for f in "${FARR[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply this greatly by using a `while` loop and the `read` command. The `read` before the loop is there to consume the first line of the input file without using it. There's no need for arrays; just use each input line as you read it.

```
dir='gauss_data'
declare -i N=0
{
    read
    while read f n rest; do
        ./gauss_and_noise.py -i "$dir/$f.out" -d \
                             --save "$dir/$f.out.plog.png" --n0 $n
        ((n++))
    done
} < $dir/all.dat
```